# Save MQ Queue messages to separate files

Tags: queue, ibm-mq, message

I am using q program to read messages from a MQ queue and write them to a file. But, is there any way I can save each message into a separate file along with RFH header using q instead of writing to one large file?

`q -iInputQueue > OutputFile.txt`

I searched for options in q manual but couldn't get one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for looking in to this. I found the RFHUtil supportpac provides this functionality.
Download it from IBM website. The binaries are provided for AIX in a separate folder.

Use the program *mqcapture* program and pass the *parmcapt.txt* file with the right settings to save each message in a separate file.

That works good.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - no.

The easiest thing to do would be to customize some of the sample programs such as `amqsget.c` to do what you want.  Peeling off one message at a time to a file is a rather specialized requirement and not a function the various SupportPacs currently perform.